# Compare an image against others visually

Tags: python, bash, image, python-imaging-library

First off: I know similar questions have been asked before a lot of times, but none of them help in my case.

I need a way to compare one image against a lot of other images visually by their content only. Metadata like EXIF and even the size of the image may change. The images might also have a slightly different (they are all JPEG though) compression or very minor JPEG artifacts, almost invisible to the human eye. I need this comparison to be done without having any image but the one that is being uploaded at the time stored. Python3 or bash would be prefered.

**What came into my mind so far and why it wouldn't work:**

- diff / md5 / sha512 / etc. – A checksum test would not work because both file- and imagesize might differ. There can also be a very slight pixel change due to JPEG compression.
- ImageMagick's compare tool – Doesn't work because the images to compare against aren't saved locally. Also, it is a huge amount (50k+) and I need this check to be performed quite often (up to several times in one minute)
- Imgdupes – Same as above applies
- Python PIL's ImageChops difference method – Same as above applies
- Saving a hashed value of PIL's histogram to a database – This might not be accurate enough (since different images can have a histogram too similar) and an exact check would not work since slight differences due to JPEG compression can occur
- Getting each pixel's RGB value using PIL and hashing that into a DB – This is a good solution, but it would not work with different imagesizes and also not with minor compression changes
- Scaling each image to the same size, then doing the above – Probably the best I came up with so far, but it would still not take minor changes into account.

That's all I came up with so far. What I am looking for would preferably be a tool or way to convert the visual content of an image into a string and then being able to compare that string to the string of another image, getting a non-boolean result (as in, visually same but technically different images will be reported as a duplicate still).

What just came into my mind would be to take the incoming picture, compare it against a fully black image using ImageMagick, save that value and then compare that value against new images. I have absolutely no idea if and how good that would work in practice though. I can imagine this might result in non-duplicates being reported as a duplicate.

Comment: Can you point me to one? All I've found was essentially either imagemagick's compare, PIL or imgdupes. Anything else I found does not handle visually similar but technically slightly different images well enough.

Comment: Look for perceptual hashes. Imagemagick has one. The hash values are 42 floats stored in the image meta data. you can then extract from several image and compute the Sum Squared Difference. Or find other perceptual hashes. See https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi6stTCzJjaAhVG8WMKHfUBApwQFghAMAM&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.phash.org%2F&usg=AOvVaw0dKzISw6vlbP2Ap_5sW05x and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perceptual_hashing

Comment: Perceptual hashes would better suit such kind of requirements as mentioned by @fmw42. The latest version of OpenCV has this feature added and can be used directly to calculate perceptual hashes which you can then store in DB or add to metadata.